# EF OrderBy Multi Properties

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

Entity Framework have method for ordering:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, bool ascending, string propertyName) where T : class
{
    return ascending ? 
      query.OrderBy(p => EF.Property<object>(p, propertyName)) :
      query.OrderByDescending(p => EF.Property<object>(p, propertyName));
}
```

But I have multiple `orderby` clauses with method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<Tuple<bool, string>> sortModels)
{
    var expression = query.Expression;
    bool first = true;

    foreach ((var desc, var item) in sortModels)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, item);
        var method = desc ?
                    (first ? "OrderByDescending" : "ThenByDescending") :
                    (first ? "OrderBy" : "ThenBy");
        expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method,
                    new Type[] { query.ElementType, selector.Type },
                    expression, Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(selector, parameter)));
        first = false;
    }

    return first ? query : query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
}
```

My question is: is there an EF native form?

Comment: What is *EF native form*? Both methods are correct, second is much mature.

Comment: Ef native form is first exampled a solution, I don't need to use reflection or others libs

Comment: I think you are wrong. Even just simple `Queryable.OrderBy` call uses reflection and expression tree building. So, you can accept any dynamic expression tree building for achieving your needs. EF translates expression tree, so feed it with correct expression tree.